# URL-rewriting stopped working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect

For this website www.demoeial.be, I used URL-rewriting for every link. This is the rewrite rule for the articles:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^artikels/([0-9]+)/(.*).dhtml http://www.demoeial.be/articles.php?article_id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^prints/([0-9]+)/(.*).dhtml http://www.demoeial.be/print.php?action=view&print_id=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^auteur/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*).dhtml http://www.demoeial.be/author.php?action=view&author_id=$1&page=$2 [NC]

RewriteRule ^nieuws/([0-9]+)/$ category.php?cat_id=1&page=$1
RewriteRule ^dossiers/([0-9]+)/(.*)/([0-9]+)/$ dossiers.php?dossier_id=$1&page=$3
RewriteRule ^interviews/([0-9]+)/$ category.php?cat_id=4&page=$1
RewriteRule ^reportages/([0-9]+)/$ category.php?cat_id=5&page=$1
RewriteRule ^cultuur/([0-9]+)/$ category.php?cat_id=6&page=$1
RewriteRule ^opinie/([0-9]+)/$ category.php?cat_id=2&page=$1
RewriteRule ^satire/([0-9]+)/$ category.php?cat_id=7&page=$1
RewriteRule ^politiek-filosofie/([0-9]+)/$ category.php?cat_id=8&page=$1
RewriteRule ^literair/([0-9]+)/$ category.php?cat_id=9&page=$1
RewriteRule ^muziek/([0-9]+)/$ category.php?cat_id=10&page=$1
RewriteRule ^meewerken/$ content.php?content_id=2
RewriteRule ^over/$ content.php?content_id=1
RewriteRule ^zoeken/(.*)/([0-9]+)/$ search.php?search_words=$1&page=$2

RewriteRule ^print/([0-9]+)/$ print.php?page=$1


<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/javascript application/x-javascript application/javascript text/x-component text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
</IfModule>
```

It was working before, but since some time the browsers apparently is redirected to the server link. For example http://www.demoeial.be/artikels/10436/Studentenoverleg-VGC-levert-weinig-op.dhtml goes to http://www.demoeial.be/articles.php?article_id=10436. Before it never showed that second link, and kept showing the good looking one. I do not know what happened or changed, but it was working before. Any guesses?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: With the conf you have here, there is no reason for a Redirect to happen. My guess would be that it is triggered by a previous rule in your `.htaccess`

Comment: @cheesemacfly problem is, there is no other rule in the htaccess. I am starting to think that some server setting or something has changed

Comment: Well if it is your full `.htaccess` then the issue comes from somewhere else. As any of the config files related to Apache been modified?

Comment: @cheesemacfly I edited the post above with the complete .htaccess file. I am thinking about changing any config files, but can't think of any. I just checked php.ini in the root etc folder, but can't seem to find anything out of the ordinary. I also checked a different site on the same server. I use practically the same htaccess there, so if there ain't something wrong with this htcaccess, then it's definately server related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt if *it was working before*. A rule starting with `http://` in the substitution URL creates a redirect. Change this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^artikels/([0-9]+)/(.*).dhtml http://www.demoeial.be/articles.php?article_id=$1 [NC]
```

To this:

```
RewriteRule ^artikels/([0-9]+)/(.*).dhtml articles.php?article_id=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it. Such a simple solution. Have been searching a solution for days now! Apparently along the way I must have changed the rewrite url.

Comment: Well, this is not exactly true. If the rule start with `http://` and then match the current host, it does NOT create a redirect. (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)